# Convert .html file to image

Tags: html, image

I am looking for any utility that will faithfully convert a .html file to an image format -- preferable png or jpeg.  I have Googled for hours and downloaded a dozen or so free trials but nothing seems to do the job.  Adobe Acrobat Pro almost worked but it is determined to shrink table cells to fit on a page rather than shrinking the whole table.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: assuming you're trying to do too many pages to simply printscreen them all together?

Comment: Would something like [this](http://awesomium.com/) work?

Comment: I use the Screengrab extension for Firefox. Chrome has a few similar ones.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=130435) can help.

Comment: There are a number of add ons for Firefox that will do this. What exactly is your use case?

Comment: Thanks all.  Writing the question out gave me the solution.  I just needed to add nowrap to the table cells and Acrobat works just fine.

Answer (score 20):

I am using wkhtmltoimage.

It is a fast command line tool which uses the webkit library to render any website.
There are two versions one to generate pdfs and one to generate images.

wkhtmltoimage works with Windows, Linux and Mac.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

```
/wkhtmltoimage-i386 -H
Name:
  wkhtmltoimage 0.10.0 rc2

Synopsis:
  wkhtmltoimage [OPTIONS]... <input file> <output file>

Description:
  Converts an HTML page into an image, 

General Options:
      --allow <path>                  Allow the file or files from the specified
                                      folder to be loaded (repeatable)
      --checkbox-checked-svg <path>   Use this SVG file when rendering checked
                                      checkboxes
      --checkbox-svg <path>           Use this SVG file when rendering unchecked
                                      checkboxes
      --cookie <name> <value>         Set an additional cookie (repeatable)
      --cookie-jar <path>             Read and write cookies from and to the
                                      supplied cookie jar file
      --crop-h <int>                  Set height for croping
      --crop-w <int>                  Set width for croping
      --crop-x <int>                  Set x coordinate for croping
      --crop-y <int>                  Set y coordinate for croping
      --custom-header <name> <value>  Set an additional HTTP header (repeatable)
      --custom-header-propagation     Add HTTP headers specified by
                                      --custom-header for each resource request.
      --no-custom-header-propagation  Do not add HTTP headers specified by
                                      --custom-header for each resource request.
      --debug-javascript              Show javascript debugging output
      --no-debug-javascript           Do not show javascript debugging output
                                      (default)
      --encoding <encoding>           Set the default text encoding, for input
  -H, --extended-help                 Display more extensive help, detailing
                                      less common command switches
  -f, --format <format>               Output file format (default is jpg)
      --height <int>                  Set screen height (default is calculated
                                      from page content) (default 0)
  -h, --help                          Display help
      --htmldoc                       Output program html help
      --images                        Do load or print images (default)
      --no-images                     Do not load or print images
  -n, --disable-javascript            Do not allow web pages to run javascript
      --enable-javascript             Do allow web pages to run javascript
                                      (default)
      --javascript-delay <msec>       Wait some milliseconds for javascript
                                      finish (default 200)
      --load-error-handling <handler> Specify how to handle pages that fail to
                                      load: abort, ignore or skip (default
                                      abort)
      --disable-local-file-access     Do not allowed conversion of a local file
                                      to read in other local files, unless
                                      explecitily allowed with --allow
      --enable-local-file-access      Allowed conversion of a local file to read
                                      in other local files. (default)
      --manpage                       Output program man page
      --minimum-font-size <int>       Minimum font size
      --password <password>           HTTP Authentication password
      --disable-plugins               Disable installed plugins (default)
      --enable-plugins                Enable installed plugins (plugins will
                                      likely not work)
      --post <name> <value>           Add an additional post field (repeatable)
      --post-file <name> <path>       Post an additional file (repeatable)
  -p, --proxy <proxy>                 Use a proxy
      --quality <int>                 Output image quality (between 0 and 100)
                                      (default 94)
      --radiobutton-checked-svg <path> Use this SVG file when rendering checked
                                      radiobuttons
      --radiobutton-svg <path>        Use this SVG file when rendering unchecked
                                      radiobuttons
      --readme                        Output program readme
      --run-script <js>               Run this additional javascript after the
                                      page is done loading (repeatable)
  -0, --disable-smart-width           Use the specified width even if it is not
                                      large enough for the content
      --stop-slow-scripts             Stop slow running javascripts (default)
      --no-stop-slow-scripts          Do not Stop slow running javascripts
                                      (default)
      --transparent                   Make the background transparent in pngs
      --use-xserver                   Use the X server (some plugins and other
                                      stuff might not work without X11)
      --user-style-sheet <url>        Specify a user style sheet, to load with
                                      every page
      --username <username>           HTTP Authentication username
  -V, --version                       Output version information an exit
      --width <int>                   Set screen width (default is 1024)
                                      (default 1024)
      --window-status <windowStatus>  Wait until window.status is equal to this
                                      string before rendering page
      --zoom <float>                  Use this zoom factor (default 1)

Specifying A Proxy:
  By default proxy information will be read from the environment variables:
  proxy, all_proxy and http_proxy, proxy options can also by specified with the
  -p switch

  <type> := "http://" | "socks5://"
  <serif> := <username> (":" <password>)? "@"
  <proxy> := "None" | <type>? <sering>? <host> (":" <port>)?

  Here are some examples (In case you are unfamiliar with the BNF):

  http://user:password@myproxyserver:8080
  socks5://myproxyserver
  None

Contact:
  If you experience bugs or want to request new features please visit 
  <http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/list>, if you have any problems
  or comments please feel free to contact me: <uuf6429@gmail.com>
```

Demo:

```
./wkhtmltoimage-i386 "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907986/convert-html-file-to-image/11908055#11908055" demo.png
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: This link says how to implement wkhtmlimage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617720/use-wkhtmltoimage-in-php/22797539#22797539

Comment: How did you manage to generate the images? In my usage they are missing, as well as the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a command line program, give [IECapt](http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/) a try. It uses the Internet Explorer rendering engine. There is also a cross platform utility named [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) – which one I haven't tried. One note to the file parameter of IECapt: It worked only by specifying the full path of the file. It seems, that relative pathes are not recognized. Quotes in the path are allowed like: `--file:"C:\....."`

Answer (score 1):

There's also PhantomJS (cf. http://phantomjs.org).
I use it in a search engine written in PHP to generate the Web site thumbnails.
Like wkhtmltoimage, it is a command line program based on WebKit, and can generate images and PDFs. But as it's a full browser, it uses JavaScript to do the processing.

EDIT: see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture for a concrete sample of image rendering.