# Use wkhtmltoimage in php

Tags: php

When I use wkhtmltoimage in terminal,it works well.
But it has some problem when used in php.
It is the problem:
The php code:

```
<?php
  $command = './wkhtmltoimage --width 164 --height 105 --quality 100 --zoom 0.2 http://www.google.com file/test.jpg';
  ob_start();
  passthru($command);
  $content = ob_get_clean();
  echo $command;
  echo $content;
?>
```

It works.And when I try the same command in terminal,it works well too.

But when I try other links,it can't work well.

```
<?php
  $command = './wkhtmltoimage --width 164 --height 105 --quality 100 --zoom 0.2 http://codante.org/linux-php-screenshot file/test.jpg';
  ob_start();
  passthru($command);
  $content = ob_get_clean();
  echo $command;
  echo $content;
?>
```

It does work.But when I try same command in terminal.It works!
Plz help me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that `passthru` is disabled in the `php.ini` file used for the web server for security reasons. Try executing the following code:

```
function passthru_enabled() {
    $disabled = explode(', ', ini_get('disable_functions'));
    return !in_array('exec', $disabled);
}
if (passthru_enabled()) {
    echo "passthru is enabled";
} else {
    echo "passthru is disabled";
}
```

If it is disabled, there's really nothing you can do unless you can edit the php.ini file.

Edit: Also, make sure you enable error reporting in your code, which should also display some sort of warning if you try to use a disabled function. Put this in your code:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

**Edit:**

If `passthru` is enabled, then the only reason I can think of that a command should execute correctly by the command line and not PHP is because it is not being passed correctly to the command line. Try adding quotes around the arguments using [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

```
$url = escapeshellarg('http://codante.org/linux-php-screenshot');
$command = "./wkhtmltoimage --width 164 --height 105 --quality 100 --zoom 0.2 $url file/test.jpg";
```

You may also want to take advantage of the second parameter of `passthru`, which returns the exit status of the command. A non-zero value indicates that there was an error.

```
passthru($command, $status);
if ($status != 0) {
    echo "There was an error executing the command. Died with exit code: $status";
}
```

For a list of these exit codes to help you debug what is happening see [Exit codes with special meanings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)

Comment: I am sure that passthru() is enabled.My problem is my php code that cantains the command `'./wkhtmltoimage --width 164 --height 105 --quality 100 --zoom 0.2 (website url) file/test.jpg'` can be useful for screenshooting some websites,not all websites.But the same command used in terminal can screenshoot all websites.

Comment: If I have checkbox in the HTML file, then while converting to image the checkbox has 25pixels of width and height and it hide the label. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Senthil please create a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I used the PHP exec keyword with a batch file.
It works perfectly with wkhtmltoimage:
Here goes: I created 1.html and 1.bat and 1.php and saved all 3 files into htdocs.

1.bat:

```
cd\
cd c:\program files\wkhtmltopdf\bin
wkhtmltoimage http://localhost/1.html C:\howzit.jpg
rem (you can write to C: but not write to htdocs folder.)
```

1.php:

```
<?php
    exec("1.bat");
    echo "done c:\howzit.jpg";
?>
```

PS these won't work due to security settings inside localhost:

```
<img src = "c:\howzit.jpg">
<img src = "file:///c:/howzit.jpg">
But you will find the new jpg file in your C: directory (WinXP)
```